# Why did for's performance on Lists decrease in .NET 7?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0

[Nick Chapsa's video](https://youtu.be/LfgBm5M8eUM) points this out:

```cs
[Benchmark]
public void For_List() { 
    for (int i = 0; i < ItemsList.Count; i++) {
        var item = ItemsList[i]; 
    }
}

[Benchmark]
public void ForEach_List() { 
    foreach (var item in ItemsList) {}
}
```

Has these runtimes in .NET 6.0 and .NET 7.0:

```
+───────────────+──────────+───────────+──────────+─────────+
| Method        | Runtime  | Mean      | Error    | StdDev  |
+───────────────+──────────+───────────+──────────+─────────+
| For_List      | .NET 6.0 | 320.2 ns  | 0.90 ns  | 0.80 ns |
| ForEach_List  | .NET 6.0 | 633.3 ns  | 1.16 ns  | 0.97 ns |
| For_List      | .NET 7.0 | 422.48 ns | 0.84 ns  | 0.78 ns |
| ForEach_List  | .NET 7.0 | 426.4 ns  | 1.16 ns  | 1.09 ns |
+───────────────+──────────+───────────+──────────+─────────+
```

In .NET 6.0, the `for` loop method was faster than it is in .NET 7.0.

How come? In the video Nick shows that the CIL has no difference, so he speculated the difference is due to changes in the JIT compiler.

Comment: [Chris Sinclair's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfgBm5M8eUM&lc=Ugzn5YQf8rnDI3J5Xmd4AaABAg) comment on it probably explains the difference. The for loop version of the code has to lookup the count and the current value on the list for every iteration, the compiler can't assume it is fixed. The jit compiler might have made some improvements to the all around list implementation specifically since it's a ubiquitous class.

Comment: It doesn't actually tests the for-loop, it tests the ability of the jitter to eliminate dead code.  Looks like in the quest to improve foreach, it lost the ability to remove the unnecessary statement in the body.  Not so sure that really matters, best to file an issue at github.com

Comment: The documentation for Benchmark.NET itself says that you should avoid Dead Code Elimination: https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/good-practices.html#avoid-dead-code-elimination. The sample "benchmark" code is all about dead code.

Comment: This issue is tracked here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/76638